# Difference between Caching options provided by Spring Boot and Resilience4j cache

Tags: resilience4j

Resilience4j version: 1.2.0

Java version: 1.8

Problem description:
I am trying to explore different patterns provided by resilience4j. I am trying to stick to annotations vs functional programming. But when it comes to resilience4j cahce, I am bit confused, as I couldn't find an working example of the same. I was able successfully try out other patterns.
My confusion is around spring boot cache and resilience4j cache. Are they same or functionally different? Can I use them interchangingly? Is there any github repository giving an usecase and explanation for the resilience4j cache? Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I got an response from the author Robert Winkler on github, who wrote  Resiliance4j-cache component. Below is his resonse.

RobWin:
Hi,

You can stick with Spring Caching Abstraction and Annotations.
Resilience4j-cache is currently not part of the Spring Boot starter and there are no plans to add it.
Resilience4j-cache was created by me when I had to use JCache API and Hazelcast and I wanted to protect my application from runtime exception which were thrown by Hazelcast.